# Google photos on iPhone, only upload select photos

Tags: iphone, delete-file, google-photos

I have an iPhone and I want to create an album my friends, many of whom are Android users, can add photos to. I downloaded the app on my phone for this purpose. In order to add any photos the phone first wants to uploade all my photos to Google Photos. I don't want this to happen. I only want to add select photos to the app. Further I don't want to create a situation where I remove a photo from Google Photos which then removes the photos from my phone and other devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below steps in your Iphone.

- Go to app store and download google photos
- Login to your account in google photos now go to settings in google photos there you 
  will see "BACKUP & SYNC"
- Open it and turn-off the Backup & Sync from it.

Now you can upload your photos to google drive

- Sign in your google account
- Click on "+"Sign and create a new folder and give the Name you want.
- After that open that folder and  click on the "+"sign it will ask you from where you 
  want to add photos so click your file destination and select the photos you want to 
  upload and click upload.
- Now if your friends are using Android phone then no worry just generate the share link 
  and give permission of Read,Write so that they can view and edit the photos or can add 
  the photos in it.

Let me know whether it worked or not.